# When to use capital in hand writen postie notes

Tags: capitalization

I have been wondering when I need to use all capital when writing a hand note to someone. What I refer to is generally writing on postie note. Should I be writing this in capital or follow the normal rules.

For example, I have a hand written resources board at my office. This board fills with postie notes with peoples' name on it. Most of these names were written with all capital. Is this correct?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The question is what do you want the post-it for. Usually post-its on the wall are supposed to be readable from half across the room. Hence, the capital letters, which mostly make it easier to read from afar.

It's the same reasons a lot of warning labels are all capital letters. There's just a better readability as long as it's just a handful of words.

Also handwriting in all capital letters is usually more readable then the actual handwriting.

Comment: What's with the minus?

Comment: You have run into the site's eternal curse -- the driveby downvoter. No one knows the reason for this particular discourtesy. I can guess that the DBDVer was displeased that you answered a question that didn't meet his or her standards for consideration.

Comment: @Laetitia as deadrat already says, one cannot tell about with those down votes. Maybe it was just because the question is not that good - which is why it's currently on hold - sometimes people down vote answers to *bad* questions as well. Your answer is reasonable enough and there is really not much use in references here.